# Closing Visio from VBS file

Tags: vba, vbscript, visio

Currently I open Visio from VBS file and do work. However, every time the macro ends, the Visio.exe still lingers in the 'Active Processes' under Task Manager.

Problem is, when I run the macro multiple times, I get multiple Visio.exe just sitting there.

How can I effectively close the Visio file (hence terminating the process)?

Here is my code:

```
Sub MacroExample()

    Dim AppVisio 
    Set AppVisio = CreateObject("visio.InvisibleApp")
    Dim vsoDoc

    Set vsoDoc = AppVisio.Documents.Open("filepath\file.vsd")

    vsoDoc.ExecuteLine ("MacroName")
    Set vsoDoc = Nothing
    set AppVisio = nothing
    vsoDoc.close
    appvisio.quit
End Sub
```

These 2 lines are not working as intended? (Based on my internet search, documents I've came across all talk about similar code. I thought these 2 would close the process)

```
    vsoDoc.close
    appvisio.quit
```

Any help/pointers in the right direction is appreciated! (Note all the code here and inside Visio is working as intended)

Comment: I'd keep the `.Close` and `.Quit` calls, but try adding `Set appVisio = Nothing` at the end, in case.

Comment: Rearranging the code worked! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is rearranging of code

```
vsoDoc.close
appvisio.quit

'put this at the end instead of beginning   
Set vsoDoc = Nothing
set AppVisio = nothing
```